# BLE characteristic is nil when the service is not nil running in iPhone

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

In my project ,I use BLE peripheral connected with my iPhone. When I beyond the maximum connected distance , the communication is disconnected, and then I come back,the communication become connected. But after re-connected, the characteristic can not write data ! It seem that the characteristic is nil but the service is not nil. I must run my app again so that the characteristic can write data normally. Dose anyone have the same situation,or any idea ? Wait for help.

```
    -(void) writeCharacteristicValue:(int )value forCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)charateristic  type:(CBCharacteristicWriteType ) type
{
    NSLog(@"writeCharacteristicValue");

    NSData  *data   = nil;
    u8 val = value;

    if (nil == servicePeripheral)
    {
        NSLog(@"Not connected to a peripheral");
        return ;
    }

    if (nil == charateristic)
    {
        NSLog(@"No valid characteristic");
        return;
    }

    data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&val length:sizeof (val)];
    [servicePeripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic: charateristic type:type];
    NSLog(@"dataWithBytes value %d",val);
}
CoreBluetooth[WARNING] <CBConcreteCharacteristic: 0x1ed5f1c0> is not a valid characteristic for peripheral <CBConcretePeripheral: 0x20002520 UUID = <CFUUID 0x20078a60> BE196610-C2A1-5D22-3E71-6851718F9672, Name = "Finder", IsConnected = YES>
```

It sometimes NSLog "No valid characteristic" , so I think the characteristic is nil .

Comment: A little code to see why characteristic is null?

Comment: I add the warning above. I change my CBCharacteristicWriteType which is CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse now, but it doesn't help, I don't know what can I do....@Larme

Comment: Post the code when you call your method, and the when you use/set theses parameters...

Comment: The problem is solved! Thank you all the same ! @Larme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved ! 
  I put the connected services in an NSMutableArray, when the peripheral disconnected, I failed to remove the service from the connected-service array. So the next time I get the service from the array, it return the wrong service which had been release.
  Now,I change my code and remove the disconnected service in time. It works well!

Comment: Can you please post the Code ? I am facing issue in writing data from central to Peripheral.